# Jquery animation is getting stuck mid animation on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fullpage.js

I have am using a callback function on a FullPage.js site which calls a function to run a series of animation on 20 divs. The problem is it sometimes works, but often times breaks. I've realized that it breaks on 3 particular slides. Each of them have slideshow carousels on them. I have reason to believe these are to blame in some shape or form.

However, when I set the slideshow divs to display:none, the animation work flawlessly.

You can see the site at question here (the slides the dont work properly are the two About sections and the Gallery section):

http://jeanhules.com/projects/greenmonster/

Am I overlooking something here? I've been coding for a while and have never experienced something like this.

Example code for the small tile animation can be found here:

Here is the code for the animation that gets stuck:

```
(function hl() {
  var li = $('.active .tile'),
    r  = Math.floor(Math.random() * li.length),
    h  = li.eq(r).hasClass('active'),
    w  = li.filter('.active').length;

  li.eq(r).addClass('active');
  li.eq(r).find('.tileimage').animate({ top: 0 }, 300, 'easeOutBounce', function () {});

  if (w < li.length) setTimeout(hl, h ? 0 : 100);
})();
```

Thanks. A tip is ready for anyone who helps me solve this.

Comment: I think generally this is caused by the delays that appear when carousels are loaded on slides -> this causes your callbacks to fire rarely, so by the time masterAdd callback fires, all h1 callback are executed (line of letters is full), so this condition: `if (w < li.length) setTimeout(hl, 100);` prevents from starting new letters to bounce, because timeout is not set.

Comment: However this doesn't explain why letters stuck in the middle (not fully bounced)...

Comment: Yeah, its a weird little bug. I am trying to think of a workaround, but nothing seems to work

Comment: I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/49porkpy/) with a small jQuery plugin for your issue. Just for fun, maybe you'll find it useful :)

Comment: I switched it to background-position move instead of the actual div moving. with a little js love, it seems to work perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, show us the final result! Did you save it in jsfiddle, I'd love to see

Comment: I just updated the URL in the original post, but here is a fiddle with the mechanics of it... basically just an addClass to trigger CSS for the background position using keyframes http://jsfiddle.net/owupkp0h/

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but in Chrome it looks completely different then in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked out your fiddle, it seems like your second function h1 finishes looping in about 1000 ms which works when masterAdd() has a timeout of 1000ms but when you increase it to 1500ms h1's while loop ends prematurely. If you increase your h1's setTimeout function to 150, it should animate all the tiles.

Forked your fiddle and tested it out: http://jsfiddle.net/us6n382k/

```
if (w < li.length) setTimeout(hl, h ? 0 : 150); //was 100
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, That's what I realized as well. The bigger issue is related to the website. The sections with slideshows on them seem to break the animation.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me on Chrome (latest), checked /about, /buy, /fenway and /gallery (clickable slideshow page)

Comment: I can sometimes get up to the gallery section without issue, but the gallery always seems to break. Other times, all three slideshow sections break.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that when you randomly select a tile to animate, it may be a tile that has already been animated, but the animation is not yet complete. You could use the `:not()` selector to avoid that:

```
function randomInt(count) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
}

(function activateSlide() {
    var $inactiveSlides = $('[id^="slide"]:not(.active)'),
        count  = $inactiveSlides.length;
    $inactiveSlides.eq(randomInt(count)).addClass('active');
    if (count > 1) {
        setTimeout(activateSlide, 500);
    }
})();

(function activateTile() {
    var $inactiveTiles = $('.active').find('.tile:not(.active)'),
        count  = $inactiveTiles.length;
    $inactiveTiles.eq(randomInt(count)).addClass('active').find('.tileimage').animate({ top: 0 }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
    if (count > 1) {
        setTimeout(activateTile, 100);
    }
})();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvjzoLbo/)